# Is that we cannot set some styles attributes that we can set in XML?

Tags: android, xml, coding-style

```
<GridView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:paddingTop="90px"  
    android:gravity="center"  
    android:numColumns="5"   
    android:verticalSpacing="30dp"   
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"   
/>
```

For Example, the XML above defined a GridView's style,
and now I want to make a number of GridView instances using this Style. 
So I have to generate those in code.(Is there another way?)

I can only know:

```
mGridView = new GridView(this);  
mGridView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(   
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and then how to set the other attributes in code?

And if this question has an answer, the problem above will be solved:

Can we get a lot of instances defined by the same XML?
thought can include styles in XML, I need 100 instances I have to include in 100 `<GridView ... />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we get a lot of instances defined
>   by the same XML? thought can include
>   styles in XML, I need 100 instances I
>   have to include in 100 < GridView ... />

No, you can use `LayoutInflater` to add the same XML layout over and over again. 
Using xml is preferable because of the separation of UI and logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `GridView` in one layout, and reuse this layout in other views wherever you need it using the `include` tag. Check out [Layout Tricks: Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) for more info.